# Greater than ( >) with ANY equivalent in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

I'm trying to find the id of the customers whose income is greater than any customer who is 22 years old. I have come up with this query which seems correct to me, but it doesn't work in SQLite (I get 'near "SELECT": syntax error'). What is an equivalent query that would work in SQLite?

```
SELECT id
FROM Customers
WHERE income > ANY (
  SELECT C.income
  FROM Customers C
  WHERE C.age = 22
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically the equivalent condition would be to get the customers whose income is greater than the min income of the customers with `age = 22`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Customers 
WHERE income > (SELECT MIN(income) FROM Customers WHERE age = 22);
```

If, in case there are no customers with `age = 22`, you want your query to return all customers with a salary greater than 0, use also `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Customers 
WHERE income > (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(income), 0) FROM Customers WHERE age = 22);
```